# What is the best inline file comparer for Windows?

Tags: windows, comparison, diff

My Source Safe file comparer (diff) doesn't say where in the line there are differences. Which tool would I use for that?

And before someone tries to move it to SU, please note that we developers rely on these diff tools more than anyone else.

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool

Comment: not quite exact duplicate, since I am filtering by the cited feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like SourceGear's free [diffmerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/).  They built it to work with their source control systems, so it's pretty feature-rich.

Answer (score 4):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) does inline comparison. I don't know about "best", but it is free.

Comment: Many people that I know use this.  And you beat me to posting the link to it.

Answer (score 4):

BeyondCompare is excellent, though not free.   There is a [screenshot](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=TextCompare) of the within-line difference view on their website.

Answer (score 3):

The one included with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) does a decent job.

Answer (score 3):

[BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is also an excellent choice.

Answer (score 2):

I love using [ExamDiff Pro](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiffpro.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Iam using [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) Compare plugin, there is [ultracompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare.html) as well.

[Tool to Compare Two Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222469/tool-to-compare-two-files-closed)

[Google Search for "compare files"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1B3GGGL_enEG289EG290&q=compare+files&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g10)

[Best Diff Tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool)

**[And the most complete list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)**

Answer (score 2):

[Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/) is a good one.

Comment: It's the BEST one! :-) Plus they support three-way comparison + merging, and have been one of the few to compare ANSI to Unicode versions

Comment: I've been using Araxis Merge Pro (3 way comparison) for 10 years+. I haven't upgraded to more recent versions, but I had a look at their website the other day - the latest version has incredible features (image differencing and all sorts of different document type differencing). Very useful if you need that stuff.

For me its the comparison and intra-line differencing that is really useful. I use it mainly for C/C++/asm/text/HTML/PHP/css/js.

Answer (score 1):

BeyondCompare. Specially like their folder comparision option.

Answer (score 0):

I like P4Merge...

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html